# Regular expressions for anchor tag 2

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regular expression in that can replace the `href` attribute of anchor tags which as follows

Example: `<a href="otherpage.php" >foo</a>` should be changed to

`<a href="http://mysite.com/otherpage.php" >foo</a>`

Can some one help me out

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid** parsing html with `regex`

`Regex` is not a good choice for parsing `HTML` files..

HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format..

Use a parser like [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thing is i want to find the pattern (http://www.mysite.com)of a web page..and i'm able find.While crawling im getting url to other sites by matching patterns..but how can i get the internal links of the same site..i.e hiperlinks in the same site(http://www.mysite.com).